# What Happens to Our Privileges When We Go to Public Beta?

Tags: discussion

Right now, because the site is new, people have access to privileges with a relatively low reputation. My understanding is that the reputation thresholds rises when we go to public beta.

Would this cause us to lose privileges we already have? That is, if a certain privilege now requires 250 rep and rises to 500 rep in public beta, would we lose that privilege?

Or are we "grandfathered" (exempt) because we commited early on?

Answer (score 5):

The use of "grandfathered" suggests you [know the answer already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67054/can-we-grandfather-in-rep-abilities-as-sites-leave-beta). As far as I understand we will indeed lose provileges. Temporarily :-)

Comment: But **I** didn't know that, so thanks for asking :-)

Comment: My use of "grandfathered" was an Americanism. I did NOT know that the issue had been addressed on the site. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I saw with the graduation from public beta to full site on security.stackexchange.com, you lose all privileges if you do not have the new privileges requirements.

I bet this is the same from private to public beta.